# nested conditional and if no_results

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to display a phrase based on the language_code
This is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="offerte"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="no"        
}


{if language_code="it"}
    {if no_results}
        <p>Nessuna offerta al momento</p>
    {/if}
{/if}

{if language_code="en"}
    {if no_results}
        <p>No offers at the moment</p>
    {/if}
{/if}       


    <h6>{title}</h6>
    <p>{descrizione}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

the result is that it is shown only the phrase with language_code it , even if language_code is en

how can i resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Where is the language code coming from? Is it a custom field or is this MSM with different sites for each language?

Comment: Is a variable inside index.php and en/index.php

Comment: Also, how many entries are you expecting returned? Just output `{language_code}` between your Channel Entries tag pair to see the value of that tag and how many entries you get returned.

Comment: Are you following [this kind of thing](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/) for a multi-language site?

Comment: Resolved. I changed the code to this https://gist.github.com/redmile/8ad34e36bca85a7b3502
Thanks Ian

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I created a variables and changed the code to this

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="offerte_{language_code}"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="no"        
}


    {if no_results}
        {nessuna_offerta-{language_code}}           
    {/if}   


    <h6>{title}</h6>
    <p>{descrizione}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```